# MODx CMS - How to use own PHP or HTML code in custom pages

Tags: content-management-system, modx

Is it possible to implement custom HTML or PHP in MODx CMS pages?
I want to do more than the Rich Text Editor can offer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your HTML in chunks or templates, only getting the content you need from the rich text editor to use in your template, you shouldn't really be adding too much HTML to page content as this would allow a user to mess around with the page layout.

As for using your own php this can be implemented using [Snippets](http://codingpad.maryspad.com/2010/01/13/modx-custom-snippets-php/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Fishcake. I only need this for a week or so and I will be the only one using it, so it won't be risky for the users. Could you please indicate how or where I am supposed to go and write code of my own?

Comment: If you want more HTML than the Rich Text Editor offers then switch to source view and you can enter anything you like. The article about snippets i posted is pretty complete, basically create your snippet containing PHP and call it in your HTML eg. [!MySnippet !]

Comment: Thank you. (extra chars to fill the minimum required)

Answer (score 1):

The Rich Text Editor offers a source view mode where you can enter your own HTML. This would be valuable in case you want to do something fairly standard like add a DIV tad with an ID.